# JavaScript get the text before the match

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

How can I get **all** `targets` (including the *dash* `-` if there) that before *equal sign* (`=`) using `regex`:

```
<p> target="" the-target="" the-other-target="" </p>
```

- The *equal sign* is written in **HTML Code** : `&#61`;
- There's about 9-10 `<p></p>` like that with different `targets`.
- Using the word `target` is an example.

##### EDIT:

- I have to use the code below **as it is**.
  the variable `regexTarget` that stores the `regex`, will be added with more variables like this to an `array`, and will loop though them to check.
- I'll use `replace` as well.

##### The Code:

```js
//var regexTarget = / &#61 /g;

$(".line").each(function(){
    if($(this).html().match(regexTarget)){
        // $(this).html() = $(this).html().replace(regexTarget, "");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="line">target&#61"" the-target&#61"" the-other-target&#61""</p>
<p class="line">just-a-target&#61"" target&#61"" not-targeted&#61""</p>
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Your edit makes no sense - you *have* to use that code?  Then what's the point of the question if you can't change your code?   Also, that code is bad (eg `$(this).html() =` is just wrong).  Please include your expected results in an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
/[\W]+([-\w]+)&#61/
```

[image]

```js
const str = `<p class="line">target&#61"" the-target&#61"" the-other-target&#61""</p>
<p class="line">just-a-target&#61"" target&#61"" not-targeted&#61""</p>`;

const result = [...str.matchAll(/[\W]+([-\w]+)&#61/g)].map((arr) => arr[1]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
let str = 'target&#61"" the-target&#61"" the-other-target&#61""';

let result = [...str.matchAll(/(?:([\w-]*)[&#0-9]+)/g)].map(i => i[1])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question above, the word `target` was an example, the point is getting what is before the equal sign.

Comment: Exactly but without the `&#61` please... How?

Comment: Updated, check now please